# Download Facebook Autocomplete Data?

Tags: facebook, facebook-graph-api, autocomplete

I'm trying to get the complete list of Facebook autocomplete values.  There used to be a downloadable CSV file with all the countries, regions, and cities that facebook recognizes in it, but that file is gone apparently.

Before you say it -- yes, I know I can call the search endpoint of Graph to get a list, but it's a limited list and I'd prefer to have a local copy rather than make a ton of Graph calls.

So, does anyone know of an up-to-date file that I can download?

TIA,

DW

Comment: Wow.  Someone downvoted me for asking a question that many other people are asking?  Tough crowd....

Answer (score 2):

You can download countries, regions, and locales from Facebook - but **not** cities.

From https://developers.facebook.com/docs/reference/ads-api/get-autocomplete-data/:

> To download a complete list of all regions, leave q parameter blank (q=&), and set limit to a large number (e.g., limit=1000). Downloading complete data sets is only available for countries, regions and locales.

You'll need to parse the JSON response yourself and insert the resulting data into your database or other preferred local storage.

Comment: `Before you say it -- yes, I know I can call the search endpoint of Graph to get a list, but it's a limited list and I'd prefer to have a local copy rather than make a ton of Graph calls.`

But thanks anyway.  Better than getting downvoted.

Comment: I recently ended up doing some nasty hacks involving the Geonames database to get a list of cities for a specific country. *Not* pretty.

Comment: Thanks, but it's not the city names that I need.  It's facebook's IDs for each city.  Again, in the past they allowed us to download this data as a tarball.

Answer (score 0):

geonames.org -> right bottom footer "dump" :)